# file_get_contents() removing tab and new line characters

Tags: php, file

I am having an issue today with the file_get_contents() function.  When reading large files, the newline and tab characters are often removed.  Here is a minified example of how I am using this.

I hope I am not the only one who has encountered this issue! :O

Thank you for your time!

```
<?php    
$file_name = "template.html";

$data = array( 'title'  => 'Hello, World!',
               'content'=> 'Hey stackoverflow!');

$file_contents = file_get_contents($file_name);

foreach($data as $comment_name => $replacement_value){
    $search = "<!-- ".strtoupper($comment_name)." -->";

    $file_contents = str_replace($search, $replacement_value, $file_contents);
}

echo $file_contents;

?>
```

Comment: Do a "view source" in your web browser, and you'll likely find that tabs new lines are still there, then read up about how web browsers handle white space in HTML

Comment: I did. The new lines and tabs are NOT there. That is why I posted about this

Comment: I'll upload pictures to show you all.

Comment: I removed the for-each loop while debugging.

Comment: Image 1: http://imgur.com/whLZk,0wXAg#0

Comment: Image 2: http://imgur.com/whLZk,0wXAg#1

Comment: One question, is this just so that your code is pretty, or are you styling it so that your `Navigation Here` is one tab inset?

Comment: For now it is just so the HTML is pretty.  But I see an issue with this if one is requesting data from another machine and needs to explode that returned string.

Comment: Yes, to achieve the pretty code you would use `"\n"` for a new line and for tabs `"\t"`. Also, are these files not in the same working site as you could just use an `include()`

Comment: Ohhhh... Ok. So I should format the $file_contents string something like str_replace("    ", "\t", $file_contents)! Thanks!

Comment: Your example code above is for an HTML file, while the screenshots are for tpl - are you reading the tpl directly, or are you reading some other output?

Comment: @PatrickMurray That's not right - that would just replace all spaces with tab characters . . .

Comment: I am reading the .tpl file. Would that be an issue? I will just rename it now and see what happens...

Comment: Nope. That did not fix it. The tabs are still not showing in the browser. I will try IE.

Comment: Still outputting without tabs. :/ This is very strange

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue that you are having is your understanding of what will get returned. You will just be presented with a string of the HTML which will not include \r, \n or \t characters (which the browser will render as carriage returns or tabs respectively). Do a dump of your variable and let us take a look at that, then we may be able to help you at least parse the data to recreate it.

Comment: file_get_contents will read the file as is.  It's not going to replace \r, \n, \t, or anything else.  In the view source mode, you should still see all this formatting (if that formatting existed to begin with).

Comment: @ernie You are indeed correct, I just tested it out and it does keep the tabs placed in both in Sublime and Notepad. Not sure why his are getting removed then. Maybe something with his file encoding maybe?

Comment: Maybe... I am using GNU nano so I doubt it is that... I will create ('touch default.html') a new file and see if it was the encoding.

Comment: That did not do it. Wow I am stuck.

Comment: I know that notepad and sublime are saving in UTF - try and see if GNU is saving in some other format, if any. I'll see if on my linux box it has the same issues, as I am testing on Windows at the moment.